# Joomla installation

Tags: php, joomla

First I couldn't set the FTP parameter so skipped that step. I completed the other parts and then on having removed the installation directory the [Joomla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joomla) link goes to a blank page. This is the output

```
wget mydomain.com/joomla
--2010-11-02 05:02:23--  http://mydomain.com/joomla
Resolving mydomain.com... 68.178.227...
Connecting to mydomain.com|68.178.227...|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://mydomain.com/joomla/ [following]
--2010-11-02 05:02:23--  http://mydomain.com/joomla/
Connecting to mydomain.com|68.178.227...|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 500 Internal Server Error
2010-11-02 05:02:24 ERROR 500: Internal Server Error.
```

Can you recommend how to proceed and troubleshoot? Which logfile should I look in?

Comment: For future reference you might want to consider posting to http://joomla.stackexchange.com/ for Joomla questions ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by looking in the apache error log  to see what the 500 internal server error means.

Usually this is in `/var/log/http/errors` or somewhere close but under `/var/log` at least.

Use `tail <filename>` directly after getting the error message from wget and check the last lines of output, that should give some clues.

Comment: Thanks David after investigating the loggin it appeared that some special chars caused escape handling we could handle in PHP so now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming .htaccess file in htaccess.txt if present!